# Scrape Dynamic Data from Website Using C# HTMLAGILITYPACK

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am scraping data using HTMLAGILITY Pack, but the page doesn't load properly.

I need that my code should wait until the page is fully loaded.

There is some kind of work around to use browser in form, but I don't need to use that in form.

Here is the [Link](https://www.ezrsgold.com/buy-runescape-gold) I need to scrap and following is my code.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(website);
         var goldTypes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='gold-box-title']").ToList();
       var goldPrices = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='gold-box-price--sale'").ToList();

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
             {
               string  goldPrice = goldPrices[i].InnerText;
               string  goldType = goldTypes[i].InnerText;

             }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.  What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi I get variable names rather than their values

Comment: The website contains data in angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct, all the data is available in structured json in the ":buyable" attribute of the "buyable-gold" elements.

I did a quick test and this should be what you want. This will give you a list of structured objects with the data you need.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.ezrsgold.com/buy-runescape-gold");

var buyGoldNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//buyable-gold");

var buyableJsonList = buyGoldNodes.Select(x => HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(x.Attributes[":buyable"].Value)).ToList();

var buyables = buyableJsons.Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Buyable>(x)).ToList();
```

Then your Buyable class would look something like this.

```
public class Buyable
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public int game_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int min_qty { get; set; }
    public int max_qty { get; set; }
    public string base_price { get; set; }
    public string sale_price { get; set; }
    public Bulk_Price[] bulk_price { get; set; }
    public string delivery_time { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public object sort_order { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public bool on_sale { get; set; }
    public int discount_from { get; set; }
}

public class Bulk_Price
{
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but I don't know how it did? where is buyable-gold node? I can't find it.

Comment: You can find it when you view the source. Just inspecting it won't show it.

Comment: So how can I find it?

Comment: Just view the page source (right click -> view page source in chrome) then search for the tag like you would search anything.

Comment: Yes - remember inspector shows you the DOM AFTER so much JS has altered it.  HtmlAgility is working from the raw HTML source - which is often different.